# Saving picture on the server side SilverLight

Tags: php, silverlight-4.0

i have a SilverLight application and i wanna save a screen shot of my UIElement on the server side as a image

i have **WritableBitmap** where i ve put my screen shot of the specified UIElement and i wanna send it to php file to **save it on the server side**

Waiting helps

Answer (score 0):

```
// PHP Side - Saving the image on server

if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) {


$filename=$_GET['filename'];

// get bytearray
$im = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

$filepath = '....';

$output=file_put_contents( $filepath . $filename, $im);

} else{
    // write the error in log file
}
```

Comment: Thx for response but my problem is how to send the WritableBitmap from Silverlight to php file in the server